# "cout << cout" - what does the output stand for?

Tags: c++, std

After a long day of coding i accidentaly wrote

```
cout << "some text" << cout;
```

instead of

```
cout << "some text" << endl;
```

Now it printed out a memory address. What does it point to ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::cout` is an instance of `std::ostream`, and, before C++11, that had a [conversion operator to `void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). It seems your code is triggering that conversion, giving you the address of the `std::cout` object.

Comment: @remyabel I thought the `void*` operator had been removed in C++11. That is what the reference in the link suggests, but I will check this in the standard later.

Comment: could you please explain this a little clearer ? where is the operator bool() used ? Sorry but i dont quiet get it yet.

Comment: @user2664856 Nobody said the `operator bool()` is used.

Comment: @juan honestly, this comment doesnt make it any clearer either :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right. It looks like libstdc++ is behind.

Comment: @user2664856 I'm not sure what isn't clear. Could you be more specific? Does your compiler support C++11?

Comment: okay .... seems like i need to get some sleep indeed. Sorry i think i get it now. Thanks :)